# How to download file embedded as image with pd.read_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering how would I use the "Accept & Download" button with pd.read_csv() to directly download and read it into a pd? Normally I can just copy the download link and paste it but in this case it is recognizing it as an image and I cannot grab the download link.

Link: https://geodash.vpd.ca/opendata/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the button with the dev tools you can see that the form is pointing to this URL

```
<form action="http://geodash.vpd.ca/opendata/crimedata_download/crimedata_csv_all_years.zip" method="get">
```

so you could do the following

```
import requests, zipfile, io
r = requests.get('http://geodash.vpd.ca/opendata/crimedata_download/crimedata_csv_all_years.zip')
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
df = pd.read_csv(z.open('crimedata_csv_all_years.csv'))
```

Calling `df.head()` will output

```
                         TYPE  YEAR  MONTH  DAY  HOUR  MINUTE    HUNDRED_BLOCK NEIGHBOURHOOD              X             Y
0  Break and Enter Commercial  2012     12   14     8      52              NaN      Oakridge  491285.000000  5.453433e+06
1  Break and Enter Commercial  2019      3    7     2       6    10XX SITKA SQ      Fairview  490612.964805  5.457110e+06
2  Break and Enter Commercial  2019      8   27     4      12  10XX ALBERNI ST      West End  491007.779775  5.459174e+06
3  Break and Enter Commercial  2014      8    8     5      13  10XX ALBERNI ST      West End  491015.943352  5.459166e+06
4  Break and Enter Commercial  2005     11   14     3       9  10XX ALBERNI ST      West End  491021.385727  5.459161e+06
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though the question was answered, let me add some more ingredients to make this a dynamic one. Credits: @JasonGroulx

Here, let's assume that the action is going to be the get and take the action with `BeautifulSoup` and then we do read the data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, io, urllib.request
import zipfile
html = urllib.request.urlopen('https://geodash.vpd.ca/opendata/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
action = soup.find('form').get('action')
resp = requests.get(action)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(resp.content))
df = pd.read_csv(z.open(os.path.basename(action).replace('.zip','.csv')))
```